# How to catch all custom exceptions in a single catch statement with Apache Thrift?

Tags: c++, rpc, thrift, c++03

I have many different exceptions defined in `exception.thrift`:

```
exception InvalidArgumentsError {
    1: string parameter
}

/**
* Server has an problem while executing a function. 
* Execution aborted.
*/
exception ServerInternalError {
    1: string parameter
}

/**
* Server answer is empty.
*/
exception NoDataError {
    1: string parameter
}
```

This is how i catch them in my C++ code:

```
catch (InvalidArgumentsError & ex) {
  std::cout << ex.parameter;
}
catch (ServerInternalError & ex) {
  std::cout << ex.parameter;
}
catch (NoDataError & ex) {
  std::cout << ex.parameter;
}
catch (apache::thrift::TException& ex) {
  std::cout << "TException:\n" << ex.what();
} catch (const std::exception& ex) {
  std::cout << ex.what();
   return;
}
```

I want to write something like this and catch all my exceptions:

```
catch (SomeBasicException& ex) {
  std::cout << ex.what();
} 
catch (const std::exception& ex) {
  std::cout << ex.what();
}
```

If I just catch `TException` and call `what()` I just get 'Default TException' message because derived classed do not override virtual `what()` method.

Generated code by thrift compiler:

```
class InvalidArgumentsError : public ::apache::thrift::TException {
 public:

  static const char* ascii_fingerprint; //..
  static const uint8_t binary_fingerprint[16]; //..

  InvalidArgumentsError() : parameter() {
  }

  virtual ~InvalidArgumentsError() throw() {}

  std::string parameter;

  _InvalidArgumentsError__isset __isset;

  void __set_parameter(const std::string& val) {
    parameter = val;
  }

//...

};
```

Comment: Why do you want to write it like that? Just to stop the repetitive typing?

Comment: @Simple yes i have a lot of exceptions

Comment: in 0.9.3 `what()` should be overridden in generated TException subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albeit this does not really answer the question literally (@Simple did a good job at this already) I would like to propose a somewhat different approach.

Given the code posted above:

```
exception InvalidArgumentsError {
    1: string parameter
}

exception ServerInternalError {
    1: string parameter
}

exception NoDataError {
    1: string parameter
}
```

If we look at the pattern, we could - without loosing any information and without producing greater incompatibilities - change it into this:

```
enum ErrorCode
  Success = 0, // always good to have some null value
  ServerInternalError = 1
  NoData = 2
  InvalidArguments = 3
  // add more errors here
}

exception MyServiceException {
    1: string parameter
    2: ErrorCode  code
}
```

I'm fully aware that this might not fit your particular problem (e.g. if there are more exception data than just a `1:parameter`). But there may be cases where that approach could be worth considering. I've used it myself quite a few times.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop the repetitive typing then this might be a solution.

When you want to catch your exceptions, you write something like this:

```
catch (...) {
    handle_exception(print_message);
}
```

`print_message` is a function that does whatever you want with the message (in this case, print it):

```
void print_message(char const* const msg)
{
    std::cout << msg;
}
```

`handle_exception` is written like this:

```
template<typename F>
void handle_exception(F handler)
try {
    throw;
}
catch (InvalidArgumentsError const& ex) {
    handler(ex.parameter.c_str());
}
catch (ServerInternalError const& ex) {
    handler(ex.parameter.c_str());
}
catch (NoDataError const& ex) {
    handler(ex.parameter.c_str());
}
catch (apache::thrift::TException const& ex) {
    handler(ex.what());
}
catch (std::exception const& ex) {
    handler(ex.what());
}
```

To handle a new exception you add it to the `catch` clauses of the `handle_exception` function.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use c++11

Comment: You can use an ordinary function or a function object, doesn't have to be a lambda.

Comment: Ok i think i can use boost::bind for this